# How to start development in nopcommerce?

Tags: nopcommerce

I am new to nopcommerce.

Actually I have installed *NopCommerce* on my pc.

But for accessing code I have installed `Visual studio 2012` after NopCommerce.

Now I am getting an error like;

**Configuration Error**

```
An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service
this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your
configuration file appropriately.
```

i don't understand the *error*. Please anyone help me solve it so that I can run **Nop.web** project to development.

Please give some solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following link to figure out how to install nopcommerce, you should download the 'Source' version download of the [NopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com) website.

Install tutorial can be found here:

[Install tutorial NopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/79/installing-nopcommerce.aspx)